# In C why does the power function return 1 when the power is set to 1/2?

Tags: c, syntax, integer-division

When I use the following code I tried to replicate the idea that `sqrt(x)` of something equals `X^(1/2)`

```
pow(x, (1/2);
```

It returned 1 no matter what value I entered. I already solved this issue with the sqrt function but wanted to know why this is happening for the future.

Comment: `pow(x, (1/2);` is a syntax error.

Comment: Note that `sqrt(x)` is probably faster than `pow(x, 0.5)` and `x * x` is *definitely* faster than `pow(x, 2)`

Comment: `pow(x, (1/2)` -> `pow(x, 0.5)`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. That you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1` (integer literal) divided by `2` (integer literal) asks for *integer division* (on the operator `/`) which results in `0`.  From that on, you are giving `0` to a function, `pow(3)`, that converts your `0` into `0.0` (as a `double` required by the function) and this is what you are calculating, `x` to the power of `0.0` which is `1.0`.

Had you used

```
pow(x, (1.0/2.0)); /* there's a closing parenthesis missing in your sample code */
```

using floating point literals, instead of integer, the division should have been floating point, you got `0.5` as result and you should be calculating the square root of `x`.

By the way, you have a function `sqrt(3)` to do square roots, in the same library:

## pru.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* ... */

int main()
{

    double x = 625.0;

    printf("square root of %.10f is %.10f\n", x, sqrt(x));
    printf("%.10f to the power 1/2 is %.10f\n", x, pow(x, 1.0/2.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Executing that code gives:

```
$ make pru
cc -O2 -Wno-error  -Werror    -o pru pru.c 
$ pru
square root of 625.0000000000 is 25.0000000000
625.0000000000 to the power 1/2 is 25.0000000000
$ _
```

Answer (score 13):

In it's original form, `1/2` is integer division, producing a result of `0`.

Math 101: Anything raised 0, is 1.

Comment: Although this explanation of the issue is valid. Regarding the OP's intent would it be helpful to propose a _floating-point division_ like `1.0f / 2` (resulting in `0.5`) in order to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Integer division yields an integer result, so `1/2` yields `0`, not `0.5`.  At least one of the operands needs to be a floating point value to get a floating point result, such as `1 / 2.0`.  Although you can just write `0.5` and save the heartburn.

Answer (score 1):

1/2 in c++ is 0 since both are integers. You can use 1.0/2.0 or 0.5 to do what you want.